# Is there the way to develop ChatGPT's plugins without access to plugin development?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4, chatgpt-plugin

To develop a plugin, there is button "Develop your own plugin" should be seen in Plugin Store for GPT-4 model, which means to add your plugin from localhost. It is available for users who has been approved as plugin developers.
Our team is in the waitlist now, so the button for us is unavailable. To to work around this problem and save time, we are considering the possibility to develop "something" like plugin avoiding from-waitlist approvement.
Is this approach possible, and if so, where can I read about it?

I have tried to launch chatgpt-retrieval-plugin just for experiment, but the instruction says the next:

1. Run the localhost server using the poetry run dev command. This starts the server at the default address (e.g. localhost:3333).
2. Visit ChatGPT, select "Plugins" from the model picker, click on the plugins picker, and click on "Plugin store" at the bottom of the list.
3. Choose "Develop your own plugin" and enter your localhost URL (e.g. localhost:3333) when prompted.
4. Your localhost plugin is now enabled for your ChatGPT session.

As I don't have "Develop your own plugin" button, I can't test this plugin.

I can't say exactly what I expect. One view is to use ChatGPT plugins via openai API, but official docs say that it is impossible in the native framework. Now I'm looking for other options to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the launch of GPTs on Nov 5, 2023, OpenAI decided to stop accepting new plugins.

Details are here https://copilot.us/how-to/gpt/openai-announces-changes-to-plugin-submission-policy,-focuses-on-gpt-custom-actions

[image]